# "Был род бабушкина дворецкого". Объясните, пожалуйста, что это значит

Tags: семантика

Отрывок из повести А. С. Пушкина ["Пиковая дама"](https://ilibrary.ru/text/480/p.1/index.html):

> Покойный дедушка, сколько я помню, был **род бабушкина дворецкого**. Он ее боялся, как огня;

Никак не могу понять, как понимать **род бабушкина дворецкого**. Хоть убей, не могу понять ни семантически, ни грамматически, что же это значит.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*...род бабушкина дворецкого = нечто вроде бабушкина дворецкого.*

О значении слова **род** исчерпывающе написала Екатерина.

```
Почему тогда "бабушкина дворецкого" вместо "бабушкиного дворецкого"?
```

Это вариативные формы родительного  падежа притяжательных имён прилагательных мужского рода.

> Притяжательные прилагательные с суффиксами -ин- (мам-ин) и -ов-
>   (отц-ов) также имеют субстантивные окончания в И. п. и В. п.; кроме
>   того в Р. п. и Д. п. единственного числа мужского и среднего рода они
>   имеют вариативные окончания (правда, адъективные окончания
>   употребляются чаще, чем субстантивные):

https://mogu-pisat.ru/spravochnik/?wiki_name=%D0%A1%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%

Так что в современном русском языке допускается употребление прилагательных на "-ин-" в указанных падежах и с полным окончанием "-ого"/"-ому", и с кратким - "-а"/"-у", напр., род. п. - дядин сын - дядин-ого/дядин-а сына, дат.п. - дядин-ому/дядин-у сыну.

При этом наметилась тенденция вытеснения краткого варианта полным, который постепенно приобретает нормативный характер, а краткий устаревает, становится разговорным.

Это явление фиксируется в лингвистических словарях.
Орфоэпический словарь И. Резниченко даёт оба варианта, но краткий имеет помету "устар".

В Вашем примере из "Пиковой дамы" Пушкина ожидаемо употреблён вариант субстантивного окончания -а, который был в преимуществе в 19 веке, а не адъективного -ого, который стал преобладать в современном литературном письменном языке.

Answer (score 3):

*Покойный дедушка, сколько я помню, был род бабушкина дворецкого. Он ее боялся, как огня.*

Ср.: *Покойный дедушка, сколько я помню, был [кем-то вроде] бабушкина дворецкого. Он ее боялся, как огня.*

"Род" здесь употребляется в значении **кто-то (что-то) вроде**.

[ТС Ожегова](https://gufo.me/dict/ozhegov/%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4)   **РОД 2. Нечто (некто) вроде кого-чего-н., подобие кого-чего-н.** ***Эта гостиница род пансионата.***

***Этот петербургский колпак был род того колпака, какие ставили в наши далекие времена над сине-золотыми часами, чтобы в тщательные складочки бронзы не забивалась пыль и зелень.*** [Андрей Битов. Фотография Пушкина (1980-1990)]
- пример из НКРЯ

Comment: С "родом" понял. Почему тогда "бабушкина дворецкого" вместо "бабушкиного дворецкого"?

Comment: Потому что это разговорный стиль, речевая характеристика персонажа, да ещё 19 века.

Comment: @Людмила Я не удовлетворен таким ответом. Можно ли поподробнее?

Comment: Раньше, до начала 19 века, притяжательные прилагательные употреблялись в  краткой форме. "Бабушкина" вместо "бабушкиного" как раз отголосок старого способа употребления притяжательных прилагательных.

Comment: @MichaelRybkin "Бабушкин**а**" - на том же основании, что и _маменькина_ или (простите) _сукина_ сына, - ведь в именительном падеже он не "бабушкин_ый_", а "бабушки**н**". И это _основная_ форма падежного окончания (флексии) притяжательных прилагательных (3-е склонение), которая имеет в качестве _дублета_ вариант _бабушкиного_ (Михаил Панов, Труды по общему языкознанию и русскому языку, Volume 1 с. 213-214)

Comment: соотв. страницы: https://books.google.ru/books/content?id=KZbSAAAAQBAJ&pg=PA213&img=1&zoom=3&hl=en&ots=5C5wHZnoRV&sig=ACfU3U1TuQlF4iSXdJ85LZq4PFKmHdSzXg&w=1280
https://books.google.ru/books/content?id=KZbSAAAAQBAJ&hl=ru&pg=PA214&img=1&zoom=3&ots=5C5wHZnoRV&sig=ACfU3U0cN8p2rHM3suZFMFGBg_pX9Pd8Ig&w=1280